# Issue with gathering all email threads from All Mail; program only gathers first 500

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm trying to gather all my email threads from All Mail in my Gmail account. The issue is that my program gathers the first 500 and then stops. I do not get an exception error, but it does seem like there may be either a quota or something's wrong with my code.

```
function getEmails() {
   var generalThreads,inboxThreads;
 //inboxThreads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads();
   generalThreads = GmailApp.search('in:anywhere');


    for (var i = 0; i < generalThreads.length; i++) {
     for (var j = 0; j < generalThreads[i].getMessages().length; j++) {
     var message = generalThreads[i].getMessages()[j],
         label = generalThreads[i].getLabels().map(l=>{return l.getName()}).join(','),
         ident = message.getId(),
         emailfrom = message.getFrom(),
         str = emailfrom.split("<").pop();
         str = str.replace(">", '');
      }

    Logger.log(i+" "+str+" "+ label +" "+ ident);
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `search(query)`, use `search(query, start, max)`, which lets you fetch up to 500 results at a time.

See [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#search(String,Integer,Integer)) for the documentation.

For example:

```
search('in:anywhere', 1, 500)
```

followed by

```
search('in:anywhere', 501, 500)
```

and so on, in a loop, until you get an empty array by checking `generalThreads.length`.

At that point you have finished.

500 is the default batch size if you only use `search(query)`.

Here is one approach:

```js
var batchStart = 1;
var batchSize = 5; // for my small test

function getAllMailThreads() {
  var generalThreads = nextBatch(batchStart);
  while ( generalThreads.length > 0 ) {
    processBatch(generalThreads);
    generalThreads = nextBatch(batchStart += batchSize);
  }
}

function nextBatch(batchStart) {
  return GmailApp.search('in:anywhere', batchStart, batchSize);
}

function processBatch(generalThreads) {
  // your logic for each batch goes here - my
  // logic is just to log the thread IDs:
  generalThreads.forEach((generalThread) => {
    console.log( generalThread.getId() );
  } )
  console.log( '----' ); // end of a batch
}
```